# Сортировка массивов

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript, сортировка

как отсортировать массивы, если у меня 3 инпута?

```
<input name="name[1]" type="text" /> 
<input name="surname[1]" type="text" /> 
<input name="email[1]" type="text" />
```

как отсортировать например по `ID` поля `"name"`

Пример:

Ввел данные!

> name="Вася", surname="Иванов",
> email="email@mail.ru"

Добавляю еще 3 инпута!(JavaScript)

> name="Коля", surname="Петров",
> email="admin@gmail.com"

Получаю 3 массива, ка отсортировать эти массивы по `ID` инпута, что-бы было при выходе

> 1.Вася Иванов email@mail.ru 
> 2.Коля Петров admin@gmail.com

Вывожу!

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $i => $e) { 
echo $i. ' => ' . $e .'<br>'; 
}

foreach ($_POST['surname'] as $i => $e) { 
echo $i . ' => ' . $e . '<br>'; 
}

foreach ($_POST['email'] as $i => $e3) { 
echo $i . ' => ' . $e3 . '<br>'; 
}
```

`$i` - Это `ID`

`foreach` - работает на ура, но перед этим нужна сортировка массивов! Читал про функции `ksort`, `sort`, `usort` но так и не смог понять(

Помогите решить этот вопрос???

Comment: Чтобы отсортировать, нужно воспользоваться функцией сортировки. (ну или вручную, если сильно охота.)

А что конкретно вам непонятно в функциях сортировки? В документации есть примеры.

Comment: Вы бы не могли привести на моем коде пример? Буду очень благодарен!!!

Comment: Эээ... А где у вас массив, в котором данные?

Comment: 1 массив это переменная $e -> данные $_POST['name'] -> инфа Вася,Петя
2 массив это переменная $e2 -> данные $_POST['surname'] -> инфа Иванов,Петров 
3 массив это переменная $e3 -> данные $_POST['email'] -> инфа email@mail.ru,admin@gmail.com

Comment: О, видите, как просто. А сколько массивов надо, для сортировки? Один. Значит, данные надо перепаковать. Дерзайте!

Comment: 3 массива!

Comment: Не-а, надо один. Перепакуйте данные в **один** массив.

Comment: сдаюсь!(((( мне не осилить это!

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST['name'] = array(
    'Вася',
    'Антон',
    'Леша'
);

$_POST['surname'] = array(
    'Астапов',
    'Пупкин',
    'Путин'
);

$_POST['email'] = array(
    'admin@admin.ru',
    'none@none.me',
    'bo@bo.tu'
);
```

ID я так понимаю это ключ массива. Вам нужно объединить все 3 массива в один:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($_POST['name'] as $i => $e) {
    $new_array[$i] = array(
        'name'=>$e,
        'surname'=>$_POST['surname'][$i],
        'email'=>$_POST['email'][$i]
    );
}
```

А потом мешать по вкусу:

```
var_dump($new_array);

$n_a = array_multisort($_POST['email'], SORT_ASC, $new_array);

var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: спс, почти то что я хотел, только как я узнаю что у меня в массивах, и как вывести уже объединенный массив, функцию var_dump я не знаю!

Comment: @amf1k функция var_dump - это отладочная функция, которая показывает структуру массива вместе с данными. 

Работа с этим массивом не сложнее чем с вашими:

    foreach($new_array as $key => $value) {
        echo "Имя: {$value['name']} Фамилия: {$value['surname']} ...";
    }

Comment: <?php
$_POST['name'] = array(
    'Вася',
    'Антон',
    'Леша'
);

$_POST['surname'] = array(
    'Астапов',
    'Пупкин',
    'Путин'
);

$_POST['email'] = array(
    'admin@admin.ru',
    'none@none.me',
    'bo@bo.tu'
);

$new_array = array();

foreach($new_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Имя: {$value['name']} Фамилия: {$value['surname']} Емейл: {$value['email']}";
}

МАССИВ ПУСТОЙ!

?>

Comment: @amf1k подумайте, что вы сделали не правильно и почему массив пустой.

Comment: я не знаю(

Comment: @amf1k смотри пример, просто же всё!  https://ideone.com/HrMvEr